# How to combine multiple .csv files, and add a column with each dataset's name, in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to combine multiple CSV files in R so that I can do some predictive modeling. While each file has the same columns and the same order of those columns is the same, the names are different for some columns. So far, my code combines the files just fine and strips away the headers. What I now need it to do now, however, is add another two columns for the date associated with each CSV. The file name of each CSV contains the date.

The file names are formatted as follows: 'January 2017', 'February 2017', 'March 2017', etcetera.

So I want the two columns to be the month and year.

Below is the code I've used so far. It combines all the CSV's into one, but doesn't create the two additional columns which I need.

```
dat <- setwd('C:/Users/ . . . /Historical Data')

file_names <- dir(dat)
dataset <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names, read.csv, skip = 1, header = FALSE))
dataset <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names, read.csv, header = FALSE, function(x) cbind(read.csv(x), name=strsplit(x,'\\.')[[1]][1])))

head(dataset)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to best code these two columns into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `library(tidyverse)` way of accomplishing what you need, you can still set your working directory to where it needs to be and instead of using `dir()` you can use `list.files()`

```r
dat_files <- list.files(".../Historical Data", pattern='*.csv')

map_df(dat_files, ~read_csv(.x) %>%
                 mutate(month_year = str_remove_all(.x, ".csv", "")) %>%
                 separate(month_year, into=c("Month", "Year"), sep=" ")
)
```

This code will read all your files into one df and use the file name to create a new column without `.csv` attached to it. It will then separate the that column into the Month and Year column be separating on the `" "`

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I'm getting an error, and I can't figure out why... there aren't any extra parenthesis in the syntax:

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"      mutate(month_year = str_remove_all(.x, ".csv", ""))
      separate"
> )
Error: unexpected ')' in ")"

I should note that I'm relatively new to R, so my apologies if this is a stupid question!

Comment: @Mike Oh I was missing a `%>%` after `mutate()`. I've edited my answer to include that now.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, it looks like the code only creates 24 rows within the two columns, unless maybe I'm doing something wrong (very possible). I need it to have the two columns going alongside the combined dataset. Is that possible? So in other words, all files in my folder would be combined into one dataset with headers stripped away. Then, the two columns would be added with the month and date associated with each CSV that each row came from.

Comment: So you need 12 rows with 12 columns or something like that? You should edit your question with a desired output.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm a couple months into learning coding, and new to StackOverflow, so my apologies if I was a little unclear! Each CSV contains a couple hundred rows. So it would be a combined dataset of 10,000 or so rows, and then each row would have the month and year associated with the row (from the CSV file name). I guess I'll keep that in mind for the next time. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code was pretty good to begin with.

The following code reads each element in `file_list` and appends it to an empty list. It then binds all the elements together. It is good for batch reading files and keeping their file names in a separate column.

Try doing this:

```
library(data.table)
file_list <- list()
file_list <- lapply(file_names, function(x){
                    ret <- read_csv(x)
                    ret$origin <- x
                    return(ret)})
df <- rbindlist(file_list)
```